# VueJS: Is there an easy way to validate email and password on client side based on the server side's validator?

Tags: validation, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new to VueJS. I'm creating signup and login page and users are supposed to send the email and password to the back-end (I'm using Django) to check if the data is valid. I'd like to show error messages on form if one of them are not valid.

I saw some documentation about validation and seems like I have to write a bunch of validation code. Now I'm wondering if there's an easy way to do it.
I'd like to validate them based on the server side's validators.

`Login.vue`

```
export default {
data() {
    return {
        form: {
            email: '',
            password: '',
        }
    }
},
methods: {
    onSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()

        // validate the inputs here and shows error messages if they are not valid

        const path = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/login/`
        axios.post(path, this.form).then((resp) => {
            location.href = '/'
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
}
```

}

Can anyone give me tips?

Comment: `I'd like to validate them based on the server side's validators.` with it you need to call API to validate it. Mostly you need to add the validation on client side as well.

Comment: @varit05 yes but I mean I'd like to show validation error messages  so I think I need to do something on client side. Just calling API does nothing when the data is invalid.

Comment: Inside`.catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })` you wil get the error from the server and just show that in the client

Comment: @varit05 I think it just shows the type of response like 400.

Comment: Then you need to return the error from server and map it to the UI

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Here is the code you can follow. 
In data make a reg object like this.

```
data(){
        return{

            email:null,
            reg: /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,24}))$/
        }
    },
```

add then in your submit method

```
if(this.email == null || this.email == '')
{
  this.errorEmail = "Please Enter Email";
}
else if(!this.reg.test(this.email))
{
  this.errorEmail = "Please Enter Correct Email";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I end up writing down this.

Comment: I tried to do email validation with the above reg in Vue.js.
But got error like `error  Unnecessary escape character: \[`.
Fixed reg is below:

`/^(([^<>()\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,24}))$/`